# Clear EditText text after adding onTextChanged implemenation

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm adding a listener to an EditText field to appropriately format the number to currency in real time.

```
        loanText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        private String current = "";
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if(!s.toString().equals(current)){
               String cleanString = s.toString().replaceAll("[$,.]", "");

               double parsed = Double.parseDouble(cleanString);
               String formated = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format((parsed/100));

               current = formated;
               loanText.setText(formated);
               loanText.setSelection(formated.length());
            }
        }
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

However, when I try to clear the EditView field, my App will crash. In addition, the backspace key no longer functions.

Comment: Could you post the output of logcat? I'm curious about the error you are getting. It might be a `NumberFormatError` or (less likely?) an ANR due to an infinite loop.

Comment: Try removing String current and use if(s.toString().length() != 0) {}

Comment: please see this way : https://stackoverflow.com/a/67753559/12272687

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The problem is that your `TextWatcher` sees that you are "clearing" the text, and therefore sends off a request to its callback methods(`afterTextChanged`, `beforeTextChanged`, etc).

What i've done is to simply remove the `TextWatcher`, clear the text, and add the `TextWatcher`back to the `EditText`.  That way, nothing is listening to my `EditText` changes.

You will probably have to hold on to an instance of the `TextWatcher` instead of inlining it like you did.  That way you don't have to create one every time you want to clear the `EditText`

1. `loanText.removeTextChangedListener(yourTextWatcherObject);`
2. `loanText.setText("");`
3. `loanText.addTextChangedListener(yourTextWatcherObject);`

Comment: I'd suggest to use a boolean variable controlling if the listener should do anything.

Comment: it is Not working for me is there sample code or other solution for it Thank you

Answer (score 4):

Try to use
   `afterTextChanged`
instead. I also had many problems with the other one.

Answer (score 1):

I found this class that works great for me: 
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/UI/ConvertinputvaluetoCurrencyinTextWatcher.htm

hope that will save you guys some time.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
EditText et;
TextWatcher tw;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    et=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.et);

     tw=new TextWatcher(){
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
        }
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            et.removeTextChangedListener(tw);
            et.setText(Math.random()+"");//add your logic here 
            et.addTextChangedListener(tw);
        }};
        et.addTextChangedListener(tw);
}
```

}
 This is a Simple solution.

Answer (score -1):

You can check whether Text is empty  in onTextChanged as follows and do nothing if it is empty

> `s.toString().isEmpty()`

```
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        if(!s.toString().equals(current) && !s.toString().isEmpty()){
           String cleanString = s.toString().replaceAll("[$,.]", "");

           double parsed = Double.parseDouble(cleanString);
           String formated = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format((parsed/100));

           current = formated;
           loanText.setText(formated);
           loanText.setSelection(formated.length());
        }
    }
```