# Change EditText text from onTextChangeListener()

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am working on an Android application.In my app I have to use images based on the text.So I write `OnChangeListener()` for `EditText`.The following is my sample code.

```
edt.addTextChangedListener(this);  
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    CharSequence cs=convert(edt.getText.toString());
            edt.setText(cs);
}
@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
        int after) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


}
@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


}
```

But I am getting Exception for the above code.I know the reason for the exception is calling `setText()` from `afterTextChanged()` method. But I have to change the `EditText` text value based on the same `EditText` text change.Help me friends

Comment: Can you explain what exception you get?

Comment: I am getting stackoverflow. The reason is I am trying settext from ontextchanged() .So It makes a endless recursion.

Comment: you are setting text again in edittext once you are already done,and that's too without changing it? isn't this weird? you sure,you really need to rewrite text there,or just want to change image accordingly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just simply remove your listener before you set the text, and register it again after you are done, like described here:

[Clear EditText text after adding onTextChanged implemenation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5567373/clear-edittext-text-after-adding-ontextchanged-implemenation)

Answer (score 8):

One more solution can be to use boolean variable, so that it doesn't get into infinite callstack and eventually giving `stackoverflow exception`

```
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    if(!flag) 
    {
            flag = true;

            edt.setText("string");

            flag = false;
    }
}
```