# How to make two edittext views depended to each other

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-edittext

if we have two edittextviews and change the value in one edittextview the value of the other automatically change dynamically.For example if i have a currency converter and when i try to put the dollar value the other edittext value change with respect to dollar value at the same time.

Comment: search about ontextchangelistener https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12191394/change-edittext-text-from-ontextchangelistener

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you need to add a TextChangeListener to the first edittext field from which second edittext is taking its input.

```
firstEdText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            String input = charSequence.toString(); // This is the text entered in your firstEdittext

            secondEdText.setText(charSequence);
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        }
    });
```